# Problem With Hotbar, arrow as web site in .net framework wpf app

Tags: c#, wpf

[Image with Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhxYT.png)
This is a WPF application launched with debug of visual studio
I've a window, where show content

```
<Window x:Class="Test.All"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="All" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
</Grid>
```

and a user control, with the content to show in the window

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.ShowContent"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnrand" Content="button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" RenderTransformOrigin="0.473,0.477" Height="58" Click="btnrand_Click"/>
        <Label x:Name="showblasph" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,169,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="163" Width="664" FontSize="24"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

With a WinForms application, I did not have that problem, but with wpf yes, any ideas?
The problem is the arrows at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accidentially using a [`NavigationWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow?view=netcore-3.1) instead of a [`Window`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=netcore-3.1). A navigation window has built-in browser-like controls. These controls are not shown in the Visual Studio designer, but at runtime. The black bar at the top are the [XAML debugging tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging?view=vs-2019), that you can enable or disable in debug mode.

[image]

A navigation window is used **automatically**, if you specify a `UserControl` resource as `StartupUri`. What type of window is used or created depending on the startup URI is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.startupuri?view=netcore-3.1).

Types that display a `NavigationWindow` when set as `StartupUri` resource:

- `NavigationWindow`
- `Page`
- `UserControl`
- `FlowDocument`
- `PageFunction<T>`

Therefore, you have to set a `Window` as `StartupUri` and set its `Content` to your `UserControl`.

Comment: I had check all file. No navigation, but, I've see a "bug".
When I do: StartupUri="Windo.xaml" it work
but if I do: StartupUri="UserControl.xaml" it doesn't work, with the hotbar problem

Comment: This is not a bug, but expected behavior. I've updated my answer.